# GWT 2.8 with Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, gwt

How is our app written with GWT 2.8 supposed to make use of the latest Google Maps Javascript API?

We have been using the [branflake2267 api](https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api) but that seems to use a "channel" and "client" instead of an API Key.  Is this the correct library to be using?

By the way, I think Google should have done something about this - after all it's their GWT and their Maps API, so why isn't there a library to interface the two?

Thanks,

Ed.

Comment: there is a new binding but it seems it does not work with gwt2 but works with j2cl, but I think it might be still easy to port to gwt2 https://github.com/Vertispan/gwt-googlemaps-api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `branflake2267 api` module that your mention is quite old and targets GWT 2.5, so it may need some minor mods to work with GWT 2.8.

It may also need some updating to match recent versions of the Maps API.

You can always create your own java bindings to a javascript library using GWT's JsInterop, or update/extend existing bindings such as these ones.  It's using the old/deprecated JSNI to make the bindings instead of the newer JsInterop, so you could continue with JSNI or start introducing JsInterop.

By the way, GWT is now a community managed project and has been for many years.  GWT now stands for "GWT Web Toolkit" (the recursion is deliberate), not "Google Web Toolkit".  JsInterop is provided so that you can interface to *any* javascript library in java -- there should not be an obligation on Google to provide such an interface to their Maps.